# Android Onclick View v.getId returns -1

Tags: android

Consider The code is complete. why does the v.getId() returns -1?

I use butter knife to load, and toolbar.getId has value

```
MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements  View.OnClickListener{

 @InjectView(R.id.toolbar)
Toolbar toolbar;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.mainlayout);
   ButterKnife.inject(this);
   toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("Tag", v.getId() + " " + toolbar.getId());
        if (v.getId() == toolbar.getId()) {

        }
    }
}
```

I just don't want to use something like this to set onclick on my Navigationbuton in toolbar

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
```

my xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp" 
        app:contentInsetLeft="14dp"
        app:contentInsetRight="14dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

> why does the v.getId() returns -1

`-1`, is the value for `public static final int NO_ID`. It means that view you are clicking has no id

Comment: so im stuck with using this `      toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                
            }
        });` ?

Comment: how do you initialize the object ?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. I thing this is not possible to catch if the Navigation was clicked. since the clicked view in navigation toolbar was an ImageView without an Id.

I still use the way how i want it, I made it like this

```
public void onClick(View v) {             if (v.getId() == R.id.button1) {

        }else  if (v.getId() == R.id.button2) {

        }else{
          //Navigation Button Here
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you don't set id in xml layout. Check it.

Comment: you should give this as comment

Answer (score 0):

I think you are creating reference of Toolbar by code and not setting it's id so that's why when you checking the on click on Toolbar getId is returning -1. What you can do is first declair the id in ids.xml under res/values like:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
        <item type="id" name="toolbar />              
</resources>
```

and set the id of toolbar like:-

```
toolbar.setId(R.id.toolbar);
```

You can find more information [here](https://developer.android.com/samples/ActionBarCompat-Basic/res/values/ids.html):-

Or more about android resource [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html)